# Как правильно связать код из примера и objMan?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, меню

Пытаюсь сделать [меню](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list/), выходит не очень. Проблема в том, что в примере метки создаются в функций и они связанны с менюшкой. У меня же метки приходят через api и отрисовываются objectManager-ом. Как правильно связать код из примера и objMan?

```
        $.getJSON('http://mapzko/api/v1/getInfo')
            .done(function (geoJson) {
              console.log(geoJson)
              objectManager.add(geoJson);
              map.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
```

Прикреплю код меню

````
const menu = $('<ul class="menu"/>');

              const keys = Object.keys(menuItems)
              keys.forEach(function (key) {
                const menuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + key + '</a></li>')
                const submenu = $('<ul class="submenu"></ul>');
                const villages = menuItems[key]

                // console.log(key, villages)

                villages.forEach(function (villageName) {
                  const subMenuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + villageName + '</a></li>')
                  subMenuItem.appendTo(submenu)
                })
                // let submenuStatus = false
                submenu.show()
                menuItem.appendTo(menu)
                submenu.appendTo(menuItem)
                    .find('a')
                    .bind('click', function () {
                      if (!placemark.balloon.isOpen()) {
                        placemark.balloon.open();
                      } else {
                        placemark.balloon.close();
                      }
                      return false;
                    })

              })

              menu.appendTo($('body'));
            })
      })
    ```

[![img-1api][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px0gw.png
````

Comment: Не понял проблемы. Просто так же как и в примере пробегайте по пришедшему массиву и делайте те же действия что и в примере

Comment: У меня приходит geoJson и метки распологаются по карте objManager-ом , в примере создается  collection с метками, создается именно в этой функций и работает именно с этими метками.  Я просто не знаю как адаптировать существующий код под  то что пришло ввиду особенностей приходящего geoJson api
Ниже прикреплю код и скрин api